# How can I maintain the sync between Facebook graph api data and my app's local database?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, realm

I am using the Facebook graph API v2.5 to fetch /feed data from /group endpoints. I wish to locally cache the data inside my Realm database [a structured cache since the json data is structured in nature]. One of the issues I am facing is as follows.

Lets say 5 posts were made in total till 10 am. 
When I start my app at 10 am, it loads P1, P2, P3, P4 and P5 for a group 'X'.

Lets say 2 posts were made between 10 am and 11 am. I am using the [since](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5) parameter from Facebook graph API to load only those posts that were made between 10 am and 11 am. Lets say 2 posts were made P6 and P7.

Here is the problem. If I delete a post P5 from my app, the post is deleted from both Facebook and my cache.

If I delete the post P4 from my Facebook group 'X' it is not reflected in my app's local cache. How I can maintain synchronisation between my app's local cache and Facebook Graph API. Here are a few strategies I have in mind.

**A) Load all posts everytime**

This is the worst possible option in terms of bandwidth. Each time I load all 25 posts, if a post is there in the database but not present in the newly loaded feed, I delete it.

**B) Delete with check**

When a post is deleted from the app, there are 2 outcomes , the post is deleted successfully or not deleted. In the second case, there are 3 causes of failure

1. There was a problem with the internet while executing the delete request.
2. There was a problem with the FB servers while executing the delete request.
3. The object id does not exist on Facebook on scraping. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects) post covers how to check if an object exists or not on Graph API

**C) Realm Time Graph API for Updates or WebHooks**

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5) would be it but note that it talks about Page, User, Payment and Permission objects and not about Group objects. Even if it supports a Group object, it only indicates that something has changed, not what has changed which in my case would be a post getting deleted.

**D) Let the person refresh manually**

Well, I am not a fan of this approach but I don't see any better option. 
My case requires the app to delete one or more posts. Any suggestions or options that I may have missed?